# Android, Доступ к удаленной базе данных через ip адрес сервера

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Можно ли через гаджет на андроид подключиться к удаленной базе данных через ip адрес сервера. Многие пишут про http соединение, а про ip пока не нашел инфу. Кто может подскажите. Спасибо!!

Comment: Да, можно. Какой тип базы данных?

Answer (score 1):

Вы бы хотя бы сначала попытались бы разобраться в вопросе, что такое "подключение по IP" и т.п. Зная IP вы лишь только знаете "Адрес местонахождения сервера", вы можете попытаться подключиться по IP к данному серверу, но на нём может быть реализован протокол http и тут уже нужно знать как этот протокол у них реализован, а решения в раз-два точно нету